# How to run InfluxDB as a foreground process on Docker using Mesos Marathon

Tags: ubuntu, docker, supervisord, influxdb

OBJ: I want to start a daemon container with Marathon. I want influxdb to be the service running on the container.

1. Using the Docker run command, I currently start the influxdb service in my daemon containers using supervisord. Is there a way of starting the influxDB service in the foreground directly?
2. Is there a way that Marathon can help to achieve this?

I really want to avoid using supervisord. I feel it is redundant as a process handler.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can run the Docker container natively with Marathon. Here's an excellent guide for running Docker containers this way: https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/native-docker.html