# How to containerize InfluxDB with Docker?

Tags: docker, influxdb

Since the command to start Influxdb (/etc/init.d/influxdb start) daemonized
the process by default, so when this command is used in a Dockerfile with
the CMD or ENTRYPOINT instruction, the docker container process with PID 1
would just exist after spawning the influxdb daemon when the docker image
is run.

So what is the proper way to containerize InfluxDB?
Is it possible to start InfluxDB in foreground mode?
The InfluxDB startup script (/etc/init.d/influxdb) internally uses
a command called "start-stop-daemon". How does this command interact
with Docker?

There was a similar post about this topic earlier but that post recommended
using Marathon, which I do not want to use.
[How to run InfluxDB as a foreground process on Docker using Mesos Marathon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28953509/how-to-run-influxdb-as-a-foreground-process-on-docker-using-mesos-marathon)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the image from tutum https://hub.docker.com/r/tutum/influxdb/
They launch InfluxDB via `/opt/influxdb/influxd`. It seems the command should run in foreground.